# Error when replacing row in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am hitting a problem trying to replace a row in a numpy 2-d array with a new row.

I am trying to write a function to take an `n` by `m` matrix (n samples of m-length vectors) and return an orthonormal basis set. For the first step I am calculating the length of the first row and then dividing by that value (normalizing the first row). When I try to assign the normalized row back to the original matrix, I am hitting an error:

```
import numpy.linalg as la

def gauss_jordan(z):
    print(z[0])
    print(la.norm(z[0]))
    print(z[0] / la.norm(z[0])))
    print((z[0] / la.norm(z[0])).shape)
    z[0, :] = z[0, :] / la.norm(z[0])

    print(z)
```

The result:

```
[ 1  2 -2]
3.0
[ 0.33333333  0.66666667 -0.66666667]
(3,)
[[ 0  0  0]
 [-1  3  1]
 [-2  1  3]
 [ 1 -2  5]]
```

Where is the zero row coming from? The calculated values are all correct, but I can't figure out what is wrong with my assignment. I have tried `z[0,:] = z[0] / la.norm(z[0])` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like it's taking the rounded division instead of the normal one. 
What happens if you try to

```
z = z.astype('float64')
z[0] /= la.norm(z[0])
```

Also, what version numpy and python are you using? Is it by any chance python 2.X ?

Comment: That was it. It is python 2.7, but I thought I had protected against this with `from __future__ import division`. I didn't realize this wouldn't propagate to numpy broadcast operations.

Comment: i don't think numpy accounts for that one

Comment: The rounding isn't happening in the division, it's happening in the assignment. Try doing z[0,:] = [0.33333333,0.66666667,-0.66666667] and you'll see the same thing. When you try to put a float into an int array, numpy converts the floats to int rather than changing the type of the array.